# how to vectorize a matrix sum in a for loop using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, vectorization, broadcast

Basically I have a matrix with rows=3600 and columns=5 and wish to downsample it to parcels of 60 rows:

```
import numpy as np

X = np.random.rand(3600,5)

down_sample = 60
ds_rng = range(0,X.shape[0],down_sample)
X_ds = np.zeros((ds_rng.__len__(),X.shape[1]))

i = 0
for j in ds_rng:
    X_ds[i,:] = np.sum( X[j:j+down_sample,:], axis=0 )
    i += 1
```

Comment: You have 40 "orphan" rows at the end, is this a problem?

Comment: you're right, those 40 'orhpan' rows are not supposed to be there, i've changed it to a multiple.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this might be:

```
def blockwise_sum(X, down_sample=60):
    n, m = X.shape

    ds_n = n / down_sample
    N = ds_n * down_sample

    if N == n:
        return np.sum(X.reshape(-1, down_sample, m), axis=1)

    X_ds = np.zeros((ds_n + 1, m))
    X_ds[:ds_n] = np.sum(X[:N].reshape(-1, down_sample, m), axis=1)
    X_ds[-1] = np.sum(X[N:], axis=0)

    return X_ds
```

I don't know if it's any faster though.

Comment: thx! this is exactly what I expected, N == n case does it just fine, and its faster than strides.

Comment: @pvstrln cool. Given your edited question, the function body can be simplified to: `return np.sum(X.reshape(-1, down_sample, X.shape[1]), axis=1)`

Answer (score 2):

At least in this case, `einsum` is faster than `sum`.

```
np.einsum('ijk->ik',x.reshape(-1,down_sample,x.shape[1]))
```

is 2x faster than `blockwise_sum`.

My timings:

```
OP iterative  - 1.59 ms
with strided  -   198 us
blockwise_sum -   179 us
einsum        -    76 us
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can use some stride tricks to get the job done.

Here's the setup code we'll need:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.random.rand(1000,5)
down_sample = 60
```

And now we trick numpy into thinking `X` is split into parcels:

```
num_parcels = int(np.ceil(X.shape[0] / float(down_sample)))
X_view = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(X, shape=(num_parcels,down_sample,X.shape[1]))

X_ds = X_view.sum(axis=1)  # sum over the down_sample axis
```

Finally, if your downsampling interval doesn't exactly divide your rows evenly, you'll need to fix up the last row in `X_ds`, because the stride trick we pulled made it wrap back around.

```
rem = X.shape[0] % down_sample
if rem != 0:
  X_ds[-1] = X[-rem:].sum(axis=0)
```

Comment: thx! your approach takes less than half the time approx: 0.000556945800781 vs
0.000196933746338. I wonder if this could be done exclusively using vectorization/broadcasting.

Comment: The mismatch on end rows has been corrected (the OP chose 3600 instead of 1000).

Comment: `stride_tricks` is more valuable when there is an overlap in the summation windows.  Without overlap, it is basically the same as reshaping.